# how to remove internal server error in php when use url-rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite
my url:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage.php?unm=hr
```

after rewriting:

```
http://www.example.com/hr
```

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /myuser.php?url=$1 [L]
```

but its raise an error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the `/`: `^([^\/]*)$`

Comment: Check your Apache error log. It will tell you **exactly** what went wrong. At a guess, I'd say your `<Directory>` entry is missing `AllowOverride FileInfo`

Comment: @Petah no that not problem..

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify all the javascript as well as all css file have fullpath 
like
we generally access file putting like

```
<link href="css/pygments-manni.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now you can use like this.

```
<link href="<?php echo $path ?>css/pygments-manni.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
$path="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure of the following things:

- mod_rewrite is enabled in the apache config
- You are enabling the rewrite module by adding the following line to your .htaccess before any rule or condition:

> `RewriteEngine On`